# iterating via np.nditer function for numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm a bit new to python and wanted to check for some values in my arrays to see if they go above or below a certain value and adjust them afterwards.

For the case of a 2d array with numpy I found this in some part of its manual.

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]])

for x in np.nditer(arr[:, ::2]):
  print(x)
```

What's the syntax in python to change that initial value so it doesnt iterate over every value starting from the first but from one I can define such iterate from every 2nd or 3rd as I need to check every 1st, 2nd, 3rd and so on value in my arrays against a different value or is there maybe a better way to do this?

Comment: you shouldn't be using for-loops with numpy to begin with, instead, you should be trying your best to implement things in terms of numpy's vectorized operations

Comment: Forget using `nditer`

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you need to read some more basic numpy docs.

You created a 2d array:

```
In [5]: arr = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]])
In [6]: arr
Out[6]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8]])
```

You can view it as a 1d array (`nditer` iterates as flat)

```
In [7]: arr.ravel()
Out[7]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
```

You can use standard slice notation to select everyother - on the flattened:

```
In [8]: arr.ravel()[::2]
Out[8]: array([1, 3, 5, 7])
```

or every other column of the original:

```
In [9]: arr[:,::2]
Out[9]: 
array([[1, 3],
       [5, 7]])
```

You can test every value, such as for being odd:

```
In [10]: arr % 2 == 1
Out[10]: 
array([[ True, False,  True, False],
       [ True, False,  True, False]])
```

and use that array to select those values:

```
In [11]: arr[arr % 2 == 1]
Out[11]: array([1, 3, 5, 7])
```

or modify them:

```
In [12]: arr[arr % 2 == 1] += 10
In [13]: arr
Out[13]: 
array([[11,  2, 13,  4],
       [15,  6, 17,  8]])
```

The documentation for `nditer` tends to overhype it.  It's useful in compiled code, but rarely useful in python.  If the above whole-array methods don't work, you can iterate directly, with more control and understanding:

```
In [14]: for row in arr:
    ...:     print(row)
    ...:     for x in row:
    ...:         print(x)
[11  2 13  4]
11
2
13
4
[15  6 17  8]
15
6
17
8
```